# Method that has user skeleton in python

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm and wondering with a method that has a label 'has user skeleton' (an asterix symbol in PyCharm). What does it mean?

Comment: I think that URL should answer your question? http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/using-python-skeletons.html